# Why can't I install the React Native Testing library?

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, react-native-testing-library

I'm new to app testing and have started delving into this topic since yesterday. I wanted to write tests for my React Native app and tried to install [React Native Testing Library](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/getting-started) with this command:

```
npm install --save-dev @testing-library/react-native @testing-library/jest-native
```

Then I ran into the following problem:

[image]

I tried to find a solution to this problem in Google, but I did not succeed. As far as I understand, the problem lies in the dependencies?
Please tell me what can I do in this case?

*P.S. I tried to create a completely clean project with expo init, tried to install the library but got exactly the same error*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hit the same issue and didn't want to update everything at the moment so I solved the issue by running a suggestion on the npm error output:

`npm install --save-dev @testing-library/react-native --legacy-peer-deps`

It worked for me

Comment: This did it for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are running into a conflict with your react version dependencies. Please check the named modules for required packages they depend on.
Please have a look with: `npm outdated` and then maybe try to update your settings via `npm update`

also take a look here if you want: [updating npm dependencies](https://www.carlrippon.com/upgrading-npm-dependencies/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to update react version after updating just install the latest version of **testing-library**